# How to integrate google translator gadget like funcationality to convert the ios app language

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, translation

When we open any page in browser google provide tool to convert language.

i want to know it is possible for ios app to convert whole app or any screen of App using google language converter.

Also let me know way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool to do this but ios has multi language support that can be achieved using `NSLocalizedString`.

Heres a very good tutorial for this
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-localization-with-nslocalizedstring/

Comment: Thanks, i know about NSLocalization and used several times.